# when I press the string most of the time 2nd string it seems like muted. Is it because im a beginner?

Tags: guitar

I'm a guitar beginner. I just bought a guitar and started to learn it 1week back. However I was learning chords. But when I press the string most of the time 2nd string it seems like muted. What's the reason for that? Can somebody answer me? Is it happening because I'm a beginner? Will it change when I practice more? can somebody help me? Please

Comment: Does this one solve your question? https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104764/finger-positions-to-play-power-chords/

Answer (score 4):

Quite probably it's because you are indeed muting that string. Look at your fretting hand. Probably some part of the finger is touching the adjacent string. Maybe it's another finger? Maybe some part of your palm?

In order to prevent muting, try pressing the string with the tip of your finger, so that the last segment of the finger is perpendicular to the fretboard.

Note also, that muting is not always a bad thing. Sometimes you may want to mute an adjacent, in which case placing fingers more flat on the fretboard may help.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate that one pesky string/fret. Play it by itself. If that sounds fine, then it's not the guitar. It may well be that one of your fingers, or the fleshy part of your palm, is touching that string and muting it.

Keep your fingers curved, so the tips press the strings, and the other parts of your fingers are not touching where they shouldn't. Hold the guitar quite high, so your elbow is away from your body.

It could be that the muted string ought to be  pressed making a note. Maybe you're not pressing hard enough, or you're pressing it on the part of the fret closest to the nut. try to press close to the other side of the fretwire.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always a technique issue. Maybe the guitar neck is too thin for your big fingertips. I always measure the neck before buying a guitar. For me the distance between 1st and 6th string must be at least 36mm or they will always mute with my fingers.